# Extracting String from another string in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I have string this:

```
release/3.0.2.344
```

And I want to extract this:

```
release/3.0.2
```

pattern is like:

```
release/<number>.<number>.<number>.<number>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) in bash:

```sh
$ v="release/3.0.2.344"

$ echo "${v%.*}"
release/3.0.2
```

`%` cuts off of the end of the variable, and the search pattern is a dot `.` followed by any characters `*`.

Comment: May be worth mentioning to limit trimming from the right to `'.'` followed by digits only, you can use `${v%.[[:digit:]]*}`. What you have is fine in this case.